# Maven Shade Plugin filtering

Tags: maven, maven-3, maven-shade-plugin

I am trying to enhance/filtering some of my resources at included jars. What I would like to is replacing some of my keywords at included jars at shading phase by new ones.

Is there a way to enhance shaded resources?

Edit:

My resources have such strings: #keyword1# #keyword2# and I would like to replace them by their corresponding.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on "replacing some of my keywords by new ones". A tiny before - after example, maybe?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that a Transformer will do necessary things. I will provide details soon.